# how to read csv file from server using javascript

Tags: javascript, database, csv

I am trying to read data from this online database http://coxpresdb.hgc.jp/top_search.shtml#CoExSearch, under CoExSearch.  When I enter an id, says 1717, it will give a .csv file. How can I use javascript to read that csv file directly ( just to initalize an array).

Thanks.

Comment: You can't! At least not with javascript on the clientside, unless that is your site and you can set up CORS or you're accessing it from the same domain, as Javascript has a cross domain policy where you can't access other domains etc.

Comment: You can create backend proxy to get that data. Than you will be able to use ajax to load and parse this with js. But if you use backend it will be better to parse response on backend than in js